# Regex to split a URI string into protocol and hostname parts

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to write a regex that eliminates the protocol from a URI string and leave the hostname:

So `http://www.mysite.com` should become `www.mysite.com`

But I'm not sure what type of regex I need to cover `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `pop` etc...

`hostname = reReplace(uri, "regex to match any protocol", "")`

I've messed around with some combos, but I haven't found any examples.

Comment: The various answers below all act a bit differently - which one you want depends on whether your input URLs contain more than a hostname, and if so, do you need that stripped off - you should add this information to the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
<cfset urlstring = 'http://myhostname.site.com' />

<cfset domain = ReReplace(urlstring, '^.*?://([^/?##]+).*$', '\1', 'ONE') />

<cfoutput>#domain#</cfoutput>
```

This one will will match all protocols, and extract the domain, regardless of whether you have trailing info such as:

```
http://www.mysite.com/x/y

http://www.mysite.com/x?q=var

http://www.mysite.com?q=var
```

or just plain old

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

Comment: Shawn, sorry: downvote because your regex doesn't work (for me, on CF9, using your own code) for the second and third of your own examples!  Did you test your answer before posting?

Comment: I love when I have tested code, and then it goes up...and is apparently still untested.

Comment: @AdamCameron good catch, I've edited and posted the new pattern. Thought I had correctly tested the first one...alas.

Answer (score 2):

Might be overkill, but the java url class has a bunch of handy methods for splitting up the url.

```
myUrl = createObject("java","java.net.URL").init("http://www.google.com:80/dir/page.html?a=aa");
myUrl.getProtocol();    // http
myUrl.getHost();    // www.google.com
myUrl.getPort();    // 80 
myUrl.getPath();    // /dir/page.html
myUrl.getQuery();   // a=aa
myUrl.toExternalForm(); // http://www.google.com:80/dir/page.html?a=aa
myUrl.toString();   // http://www.google.com:80/dir/page.html?a=aa
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

It might be faster using the url class with a replace, than regex. eg.

```
str = replace( str, createObject("java","java.net.URL").init(str).getProtocol() & "://", "", "one" );
```

In my quick benchmarks, it appears the above example executes faster than a regex replace.

```
var sys = createObject( 'java', 'java.lang.System' );
var timer1 = sys.nanoTime();
var timer2 = sys.nanoTime();

var egUrl = "http://www.google.com/dir/page.html?a=aa";
var test1 = "";
var test2 = "";

// 54784
timer1 = sys.nanoTime();
test1 = replace( egUrl, createObject("java","java.net.URL").init( egUrl ).getProtocol() & "://", "", "one" );
timer1 = sys.nanoTime() - timer1;

// 66032
timer2 = sys.nanoTime();
test2 = reReplace( egUrl, '^.*?://([^/?##]+).*$', '\1', 'ONE' );
timer2 = sys.nanoTime() - timer2;
```

There isn't much difference between 66032us vs 54784us. Dont forget to run your own benchmarks. Might be more readable to use regex, even if it's a tiny bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bother matching all the combinations of protocol, because the delimiter `://` is a constant and you can use that in a look behind. This will match anything after the `://` up until the first `/`:

```
(?<=://)[^/]+
```

Note that the `http://`, or whatever, must be present; otherwise the regex won't match anything.

Edit: Note that if there is no terminating `/` you need to ensure that you're not doing a multiline regex, otherwise the match will spew over to following lines. This is easy enough to mitigate but, presumably, the string you'll be passing will just be a single URI.

Comment: If your intent is to only match the domain, `[^/]` isn't enough - you want `[^/?#]` because otherwise `http://domain.com?this#that` would be entirely matched, whilst `http://domain.com/?this#that` would only give the domain.

Comment: Also, the default regex in ColdFusion is Apache ORO, which doesn't support lookbehinds. If doing it this way, Dee would need to make use of Java's regex library instead.

Comment: Fair enough :) Don't know anything about ColdFushion, just the regex

Answer (score 1):

The regex in line two of the code below works for all the examples listed (which are various permutations of server name schemes, as well as inclusion and omission of various other parts of the URL: protocol, path, query string elements and anchors.

I have not tested it for false positives in non-URLs, or for any URL patterns not listed below.  Someone else mentioned mailto URLs... that'd require quite a different regex, which might be outside the remit of this requirement, so I did not include support for it.

```
<cfflush interval="16">
<cfset sRegex = "^(?:\w+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)(?:(?:/|\?){0,}.*)?$">
<cfsavecontent variable="lUrls">
[protocol]://[server]/path?arg=val,
[protocol]://[server]/path?arg=val#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]/path?arg,
[protocol]://[server]/path?arg#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]/path?,
[protocol]://[server]/path?#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]/path,
[protocol]://[server]/path#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]/,
[protocol]://[server]/#anchor,
[protocol]://[server],
[protocol]://[server]#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]/?arg=val,
[protocol]://[server]/?arg=val#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]/?arg,
[protocol]://[server]/?arg#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]/?,
[protocol]://[server]/?#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]?arg=val,
[protocol]://[server]?arg=val#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]?arg,
[protocol]://[server]?arg#anchor,
[protocol]://[server]?,
[protocol]://[server]?#anchor,
[server]/path?arg=val,
[server]/path?arg=val#anchor,
[server]/path?arg,
[server]/path?arg#anchor,
[server]/path?,
[server]/path?#anchor,
[server]/path,
[server]/path#anchor,
[server]/,
[server]/#anchor,
[server],
[server]#anchor,
[server]/?arg=val,
[server]/?arg=val#anchor,
[server]/?arg,
[server]/?arg#anchor,
[server]/?,
[server]/?#anchor,
[server]?arg=val,
[server]?arg=val#anchor,
[server]?arg,
[server]?arg#anchor,
[server]?,
[server]?#anchor
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset lServers = "127.0.0.1,localhost,stackoverflow.com">
<cfloop index="sProtocol" list="http,ftp">
    <cfloop index="sServer" list="#lServers#">
        <cfloop index="sUrl" list="#lUrls#">
            <cfset sUrl = trim(sUrl)><!--- remove CRLF --->
            <cfset sUrl = replace(sUrl, "[protocol]", sProtocol)>
            <cfset sUrl = replace(sUrl, "[server]", sServer)>

            <cfset sServerFromUrl = reReplace(sUrl, sRegex, "\1", "ONE")>
            <cfoutput>Extracted #sServerFromUrl# from #sUrl#</cfoutput>
            <cfif listFind(lServers, sServerFromUrl)>
                <span style="color:green">good match</span><br />
            <cfelse>
                <span style="color:red">BAD MATCH</span><br />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
<cfset UrlWithoutProtocol = ReReplace( InputUrl , '^\w+://' , '' ) />
```

This will match (and remove) all alphanumeric protocols that target a server (i.e. http, https, ftp, etc), and doesn't require explicitly mentioning the ones you want.
*(It wont match mailto or other protocols that don't use/mimic the `//server` syntax.)*

If you did want to be explicit, you could simply use:

```
^(?:https?|ftp|pop|etc)://
```

But unless you've got a specific reason to do it that way, the first is better.

Comment: Michael, the posted example works on Railo, and it's pretty simple so I can't see anything to go wrong. To be clear, the contents of `InputUrl` need to be a single URL (doesn't work for embedded/multiple) and must not have any non-URL characters (whitespace/quotes/etc) at the start.

If there is some other issue you will need to be explicit with what you are seeing and what you are expecting.

Answer (score -1):

It's easier just to use:

```
<cfset url_string="http://www.buyjustlocal.com">
<cfset domain = listLast(url_string,"://")>
<cfoutput>#domain#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It's not easier because it doesn't work. Consider the URI `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Watchlist` - your code will return `Watchlist` for the domain.

Comment: True. `ListRest` is probably what you were after here.

Comment: Neither ListLast nor ListRest work with multi-char delimiters. You could use `ListRest(url_string,'/')` - that would remove the protocol and // prefix (whilst maintaining the path), but it would also corrupt a URL that lacked a protocol - as opposed to doing `url_string.replaceAll('^\w++://','')` which doesn't.